# android php get sql row id issue

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to insert empty row in table then get its ID.
It is working but it is giving me extra empty lines in output, any idea why?
code below:

php:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO player () VALUES ()";
$mysqli->query($query);

echo  $mysqli->insert_id;
```

android:

```
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getRequest);
String str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println("row id: " + str + "end");
```

result in logs:

```
05-02 00:24:29.163: I/System.out(28787): row id:  14 

05-02 00:24:29.163: I/System.out(28787): 

05-02 00:24:29.163: I/System.out(28787): 

05-02 00:24:29.163: I/System.out(28787): 

05-02 00:24:29.163: I/System.out(28787): 

05-02 00:24:29.163: I/System.out(28787): end
```

Comment: you can always try echo trim($mysqli->insert_id);

Comment: Many thanks skrilled.. i just had to add the trim in the java code too (str.trim()) .. thanks again..